# Customize permissions of unpacked WAR in Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, permissions, war, unpack

I can't seem to find this on here but it seems like it would be somewhat typical.
I am running Tomcat 6 on RHEL5

I want Tomcat to unpack my WAR with 774 permissions rather than the 754 permissions it uses by default.  Is there a way to specify this?  I looked though catalina.policy but did not see anything that related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't controlled by Tomcat itself, it's controlled by the `umask` permissions of the user under which Tomcat runs.

See [this forum thread](http://old.nabble.com/Permissions-of-File-Created-by-Tomcat-td16792720.html) for discussion of how to control that. For more clarification, superuser.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: Awesome.  This got me in the right direction. Thanks.  Here was another helpful thread once I knew what to search for - http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/423086-tomcat-umask.html